# salesforce1 and salesforce classic

Tags: salesforcemobilesdk-ios, salesforce1-app

what is the  difference between salesforce classic and new salesforce1 app.I have downloaded both the apps on my iphone.I see some of objects are missing in salesforce classic.what else is  the differences between two.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some of the differences that you will find in new S1 are: 
  - the new record view, you are able to see now chatter feed, record detail and the related list of records that are related to that object.
  - you are able to see the VF pages that are in the object layout.
  - you have new features like mobile cards and flexipages
  - related to publisher actions in SF1 you have create, update, log call and custom action ( update and custom were not available before)
  - new APIs

These are ones of the most important features, I think, that you can find in SF1.