# Is 'Salesforce Classic' still relevant?

Tags: salesforce1-app

Has 'Salesforce1' made it obsolete? Or there is still some functionality which is supported by only classic & not Salesforce1.

Comment: Check the (mostly negative) user comments on https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/salesforcea/id404249815?ls=1&mt=8 and https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.salesforce.chatter&hl=en "Am I missing something? No calendar? No Events? I like this App however I do not want to go back and forth between Classic and 1."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, as per the Salesforce1 guide, you should still use Salesforce Classic if you need offline support. The [guide](http://docs.developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.186.0.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide_introduction.htm) states

> Salesforce Classic remains the best option if you need offline
>   support, - use of Custom App (not Salesforce1 Platform) to configure
>   and control complex offline behavior (Mobile SDK only)

This is because Salesforce1 does NOT provide any offline support at the moment. Based on the [Spring 14 release notes](https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_spring14_release_notes.pdf) and [the Intro to Spring 14 webinar dated 15th Jan](http://events.developerforce.com/en/events/webinars/spring-14?track_id=2001%5Bobject%20Object%5D), it's not clear as to whether the offline support will be included anytime soon. This has also been discussed [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21206/offline-storage-for-visualforce-pages-in-salesforce1).

Of course, Salesforce1 offers several new features that were non existent in Salesforce Classic. You can read more about it in Salesforce1 guide or threads like [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21897/salesforce1-and-salesforce-classic) and [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20935/what-is-salesforce1-and-why-when-would-i-use-it/21058#21058).